# Clarification on Set notation

Tags: number-theory, notation

The question I'm working on says: 
Find all pairs (x, y) ∈ $\mathbb{N}^2 $ with $x^2 + 3y^2 = 364$.

Can you verify for me whether $\mathbb{N}^2$ is the set of ordered pairs composed of natural numbers or is it saying that the xs and ys will be squares of natural numbers.

Comment: The first. ${}$

Comment: $364 = 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 13,$ so there are at least two ways, one with $x,y$ odd, one with $x,y$ even. Could be more, really, as there are more than one ways to write $91$

Comment: $\mathbb N^2$ is here the cartesian product $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$ of ttwo copies of the natural numbers, so $(x,y)\in\mathbb N$ means $x\in \Bbb N$ and $y\in \Bbb N$. The solution set is finite, sage gives for `R = [0..20]; [ (x,y) for x in R for y in R if x^2 + 3*y^2 == 364 ]` the answer `[(1, 11), (8, 10), (11, 9), (16, 6), (17, 5), (19, 1)]`. This may be rewritten as a factorization problem in some order / subring $R$ of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$. The factors in $\Bbb Z$ of $364$ have to be splitted in $R$...

Comment: The author apparently is not interested in a solution, he/she just wanted to clarify the meaning of $\mathbb N^2$